# Where to place external svg file to be referenced by CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to reference SVG filters from CSS. Both are external.

It works fine when the SVG filter defs are inline but does not work when in external file.
I do not want the SVG inline to avoid a bloated html file.

According to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content), it should work if the svg comes from the "same origins" as the html. I'm not clear what "same origins" means.

My directory structure is:
index.html
\css

I tried all these without success:

- putting the svg file on root with index
- as well as in the css directory
- using path url(css/test.svg#LightItUp);
- putting the css inline like so: #LightItUp {filter:url(css/test.svg#LightItUp);}

The svg content:

```
<svg width="500" height="262" viewBox="0 0 200 150"  >
<defs> 
  <filter id="LightItUp" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="420">

  <!-- Apply a uniform blur of the 
       alpha channel -->
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" 
     stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
  </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

The css content:

```
.logo  { filter: url(test.svg#LightItUp);   }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: My hunch is that the problem is the fragment identifier (#LightItUp) which is no longer supported in css background in some browsers, maybe it doesn't work in filters as well.

Answer (score -1):

Add it similar to a normal image

```
<object data="your.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="yourfallback.jpg" />
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting but the filter still did not apply